# Merge 2 TSV files in C# code cleanup

Tags: c#, linq

I'm provided with 2 Excel files that I convert to TSV files and in the end have to deliver in a TSV file. The 1st file is the main file (strWorksheetPath) and all lines have to be included. The 2nd file (PrintPath) has additional information but not each line in the main file has extra information. To do this in C# I followed [this msdn guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) to do what I have to do and it's working fine. Unfortunatly, file 1 has 23 columns and file 2 has 10 adding up to 33 columns and so 33 properties in total. I created some temp classes to see if everything is working but it looks very messy in my opinion.

Is there a way to clean up my code and make it look more tidy by possibly not having to make temp classes, condense some repetitive code, ...?

```
public static void ConvertTSVtoMontDataTable(string strWorksheetPath, string strPrintPath,
        bool closeConnection = true)
    {
        // Check if the main file exist.
        if (!File.Exists(strWorksheetPath)) return;

        // Load both files.
        var mainFile = File.ReadAllLines(strWorksheetPath);
        var extraFile = File.ReadAllLines(strPrintPath);

        // Create 2 lists.
        var mainLines = mainFile.Select(line => new TempMainLine(line)).ToList();
        var extraLines = extraFile.Select(line => new TempExtraLine(line)).ToList();
        var lines = new List<TempLine>();


        // Merge both files.
        var leftOuterJoinQuery =
            from worksheetLine in mainLines
            join printLine in extraLines on string.Concat(worksheetLine.prop6, worksheetLine.prop8) equals
                string.Concat(printLine.prop4, printLine.prop5) into lineGroup
            from line in lineGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select
                new TempLine(worksheetLine.prop0, worksheetLine.prop1, worksheetLine.prop2, worksheetLine.prop3,
                    worksheetLine.prop4, worksheetLine.prop5, worksheetLine.prop6, worksheetLine.prop7,
                    worksheetLine.prop8, worksheetLine.prop9, worksheetLine.prop10, worksheetLine.prop11,
                    worksheetLine.prop12, worksheetLine.prop13, worksheetLine.prop14, worksheetLine.prop15,
                    worksheetLine.prop16, worksheetLine.prop17, worksheetLine.prop18, worksheetLine.prop19,
                    worksheetLine.prop20, worksheetLine.prop21, worksheetLine.prop22, line == null ? "" : line.prop0,
                    line == null ? "" : line.prop1, line == null ? "" : line.prop2, line == null ? "" : line.prop3,
                    line == null ? "" : line.prop4, line == null ? "" : line.prop5, line == null ? "" : line.prop6,
                    line == null ? "" : line.prop7, line == null ? "" : line.prop8, line == null ? "" : line.prop9);

        foreach (var tempLine in leftOuterJoinQuery)
        {
            lines.Add(tempLine);
        }

        // Write output to new temp file (TESTING)
        using (
            var file =
                new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                    "output.txt")))
        {
            foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                file.WriteLine(item.prop0 + (char)9 + item.prop1 + (char)9 + item.prop2 + (char)9 + item.prop3 +
                               (char)9 + item.prop4 + (char)9 + item.prop5 + (char)9 + item.prop6 + (char)9 +
                               item.prop7 + (char)9 + item.prop8 + (char)9 + item.prop9 + (char)9 + item.prop10 +
                               (char)9 + item.prop11 + (char)9 + item.prop12 + (char)9 + item.prop13 + (char)9 +
                               item.prop14 + (char)9 + item.prop15 + (char)9 + item.prop16 + (char)9 +
                               item.prop17 + (char)9 + item.prop18 + (char)9 + item.prop19 + (char)9 +
                               item.prop20 + (char)9 + item.prop21 + (char)9 + item.prop22 + (char)9 +
                               item.prop23 + (char)9 + item.prop24 + (char)9 + item.prop25 + (char)9 +
                               item.prop26 + (char)9 + item.prop27 + (char)9 + item.prop28 + (char)9 +
                               item.prop29 + (char)9 + item.prop30 + (char)9 + item.prop31 + (char)9 +
                               item.prop32);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the TempLine class?

Also, you don't need that foreach() after the `// Merge both files`, you can just move the `var lines =` to where you have `var leftOuterJoinQuery =` and do a `ToList();` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this some more and regardless of what your Temp* classes look like, something along the lines of the below will work given the assumption that (based on the code you presented), you're outputting every column from both files in the order in which they came in.  If you needed to exclude fields, change the order, etc., that would require some changes to the below or a different solution entirely.

It's basically just reading those two files in, joining on the Split() result and then combining the two lines.  I didn't see a point in handling the LOJ logic for a null printFile line but if you need the extra tabs, you could replace the `line ?? ""` with something like `line ?? new String('\t', 10)`

Note that this is probably not the most efficient way to go about this and if your files are huge, you'd definitely want to optimize this a bit.

```
// Merge both files.
var lines =
    from worksheetLine in mainFile
    join printLine in extraFile on string.Concat(worksheetLine.Split('\t')[6], worksheetLine.Split('\t')[8]) equals
    string.Concat(printLine.Split('\t')[4], printLine.Split('\t')[5]) into lineGroup
    from line in lineGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select string.Concat(worksheetLine, line ?? "");

// Write output to new temp file (TESTING)
using (
    var file =
        new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
            "output.txt")))
{
    foreach (var item in lines)
    {
        file.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I never thought about splitting the lines on the tabs and working with those. Your solution is exactly what I hoped for. The only thing I changed is the `select` to `select string.Concat(worksheetLine, '\t', line ?? new string('\t', 8))` so there is an extra tab between the last column of the first file and the 1st column of the 2nd file and blank tabs if the 2nd file is `null` like you suggested. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped.  I had initially tested the idea using a dictionary (basically an IEnumerable<Dictionary<int,string>> which corresponded to a <Rows<colNum,colValue>> collection, but thought that might be overkill.  The benefit, though, is that the Split was happening just once per file.  Depending on how efficiently you need this to run, that might be an avenue worth exploring.

Comment: Oh, and good catch on needing the extra tab between the two files, I hadn't accounted for that.

Comment: Usually the file only contains 10.000 records max. I noticed the process also only takes about 1 second top. I'll have a look into the dictionary suggestion but like you said, it might be overkill but always interesting to try different things and learn from it.